# Hide Columns in pivot charts

Tags: excel, charts, pivot-table

I'm doing the metrics for my team and I have to create a chart with the success rate of the changes done.
I have created a pivot chart (the line chart) in excel without problems.

I need to hide one of the columns. But I need the values of that column to affect the rest of the chart.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the entire column, this wont affect the pivot chart at all.

Another method that you can do is change the text to to match your background. That way you can't see the values.

Comment: You are referring to filter the column or hide?
Because I filtered the column and the values affected the end result.
How can you hide the column?

Comment: I was referring to the Hide method to hide the entire column. To do this right click on the column heading. This is where its A-XFD letters are. In the context menu that appears select "Hide".